# Send a file as attachment in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to mail a file (image) as an attachment by just picking it from an Image Picker.
What is the appropriate way I can attach and mail a file (specifically, an image) in iOS Objective-C?

Comment: This link answers the question :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4302449/1886229

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use the method below

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Check out this image!"];

    // Set up recipients
    // NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
    // NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
    // NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

    // [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    // [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];   
    // [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    UIImage *coolImage = ...;
    NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(coolImage);
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"coolImage.png"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"My cool image is attached";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
}
```

And implement the delegate method

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Result: saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And in your interface file

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
...

@interface ... : ... <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```