# Ideal means of sending a PDF attachment through in-app email on iOS 

Tags: ios, email, url, pdf

I feel like I looked for *hours* trying to find a solution and nothing worked. Anyway, here's how I've managed to send a PDF *from a URL* as an attachment through an in-app email on iOS.

```
-(void)emailDocument:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *emailSubject = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"Hi, I'm the subject"];
    [controller setSubject:emailSubject];

    NSString *path = @"http://www.somesite.com/document.pdf";
    NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfURL];
    [controller addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"documentname.pdf"];

    //[controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"YourEmail@me.com"]]];
    //[controller setMessageBody:@"Custom messgae Here..." isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller release];
}
```

So my question is, are there any potential problems with this? And how would I go about error checking the data coming back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you've put no error checking in there to handle any issues if the PDF data couldn't be loaded. (A better solution would be to use the [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` method and actively check to see if any errors occurred.)

Additionally, if the PDF data is liable to be quite large, I'd be tempted to use  an [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to asynchronously load the PDF data in the background, prior to attempting to create the email if this is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll certainly look into your suggestions.

Comment: @KidIcarus271 No problems, I've updated my answer to better address your tweak to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to check that mail is enabled and configure before using it, but that doesnt need to be in this method.

If you are referring to error checking a failed email, I suspect that there are delegate methods for that. If mail successfully sends the message to a server, but the message OS addressed to a nonexistent address, the "from" address should receive an email.

Comment: No I have the error checking in place for if the email sent or not, I guess I meant more like if the data was retrieved successfully.

Comment: Ok. Well try the mfmailcomposer delegate methods then. Also try validating your NSData object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be nice to mention [this answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302403/how-can-send-a-file-as-attachment-in-objective-c) here, that  has provided some sample code for error checking on sending mail: