# attaching an image to email from within the App

Tags: objective-c, ios, email

i'm trying to attach image an image to a mail that being sent from the App
i'm not sure how to do it, please advise here is my code:

```
        NSString * subject = @"Hello";
    NSString * address = @"myMail@gmail.com";

    NSMutableString *strBody=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [strBody setString:_txtName.text];
    [strBody appendString:_txtIngredients.text];
    [strBody appendString:_txtPreper.text];
    [strBody appendString:_txtServe.text];
    [strBody appendString:_txtAboutdrink.text];
    [strBody appendString:_txtSource.text];

  //NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imgDrink);---- here is my problem


    NSURL *url;

    NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=%@&body=%@", address, subject,strBody];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Check this answer. Should help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302403/how-can-send-a-file-as-attachment-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind displaying a form for the user to type a message into the email, I suggest using the [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Through that, you can add attachments pretty easily. You can also pre-populate the recipients and the message body and pretty much everything else about the email. It's a handy class to have in your toolkit.