# How to export UITextField or UITextView's text to email?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Say I have `myTextField.text = @"hello world";`.

How do I save that to a .txt file and then send it in an email attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this post: [Send a file as attachment in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302403/send-a-file-as-attachment-in-objective-c)

In your case, displaying the sheet would be something like:

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Check out this image!"];
    // Attach the text field content to the email
    UIImage *coolImage = ...;
    NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(coolImage);
    NSData* data = [myTextField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"myText.txt"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"My text is attached";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName: